# TCPDF How create this box?

Tags: php, tcpdf

In TCPDF, how can I draw a box with defined width and height:

`border = 2px`

postion:

`x = 30px`

`y = 30px`?

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$pdf->Cell(30, 30, 'TEST CELL STRETCH: no stretch', 1, 2, 'C', 0, '', 0);
```